# Firebase: increment integer for nested property with FieldValue.increment(1) not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There are many similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795280/firestore-fieldvalue-increment-with-nested-object-and-variable-field-name-not-wo), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543067/firestore-increment-fieldvalue), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527492/write-data-in-to-nested-object-in-firebase-firestore).

However, none of the solutions worked.

How can you increment a nested Firebase property with the `FieldValue.increment` function?

This code doesn't have any effect.

```
    // Set query.
    let query = firebase.firestore()
                            .collection('foobar')
                            .where('id', '==', userId);

    // Run query.
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await query.get();
        return querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
            [`test.${serviceId}.amount`]: firebase.firestore().FieldValue.increment(1)
        });

    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error: ', e);
    }
```

Comment: According to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189443/firebase-firestore-increment-fieldvalue-does-not-increment) you need to have a value existing in the firestore that so it has something to increment.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

Wrong: `firebase.firestore().FieldValue.increment(1)`

Right: `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)`.

The correct code is not a method call against `firestore`.